# Poo up notification like uber application

Tags: react-native, push-notification, background, popup

Hi Stack OverFlow Community.

**Subject** : Need help regarding showing a push on my mobile app like VOIP(How you receive it when a new booking is received by the Drivers)

**Details** :
I am trying to implement a feature in my app. I want to receive a notification in the background/killed state, and it should be like a heads up notification which should not go away until and unless the user acts upon it.
Its something like the uber application where in a driver receives the request, it continues to play a notification sound and remains on the screen till the user performs some action for that notification.

Tech stack being used for this app includes =>
Front End Mobile :  React Native native
Back end :  PHP Laravel,NodeJS

Although i think it can be achieved using VoipPUSH and i am researching keeping this as by base but need help from community members what is the best way to do it.

Thanks
Arush

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Notifee](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/installation) to do this I believe. They equally have expo support. So dance around with this.